# Return type of array subscription operator for a wrapper of type ** is *&?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, reference, wrapper

Suppose I have a class A, whose constructor requires an argument x.

```
class A
{
public:
    int a;
    A(int x) { a = x; std::cout << a << std::endl; }
    ~A() {}
};
```

Now I want to allocate an array of A, and wrap it in another class B (in reality it should be a 2-dimensional array of A, mapped onto a 1-dimensional array, which is why I need to wrap it).  Since constructor of A requires argument, I cannot use new[] (…right?), so I have to have an A**.  Also I don’t want B to know about x, so my B is like this:

```
class B
{
private:
    A** As;
    const int n;
public:
    B(int nn): n(nn) { As = new A*[n]; }
    ~B() { delete[] As; }

    A* at(int i) { return As[i]; }
    const A* at(int i) const { return As[i]; }
};
```

Note that “subscription operator” loosely means that at() function.  Now my main function is like this:

```
int main()
{
    B b(3);
    int x = -1;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        b.at(i) = new A(x);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile this with g++, it prints an error “lvalue required as left operand of assignment” at my “new” line.  Then I change my signature of at() to

```
A*& at(int i)
```

and it works.

What’s bothering my is that A*&, which just looks weird to me…

Is this A*& something I should use?  Or any other way to deal with an array of objects, whose constructor requires arguments?  BTW we don’t have c++11 and boost available on our target machine…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"Or any other way to deal with an array of objects, whose constructor requires arguments?"*

Use `std::vector`, you don't need C++11 for it, neither any additional libraries:

```
#include <vector>
...
std::vector<A> myObjects(n, A(0)); // objects will be constructed by calling A(0)
```

Your class `B` could look the following way:

```
class B
{
private:
    std::vector<A> As;
    const int n;
public:
    B(int n): n(n), As(std::vector<A>(n, A(0))) { }
    // no explicit destructor needed
    // memory management is handled by std::vector object automatically

    A& at(int i) { return As[i]; }
    const A& at(int i) const { return As[i]; }
};
```

Note that vector's elements are stored within continuous block of memory and lifetime of these elements is tied to the lifetime of instance of `B`. Once the `B` is destructed, so is the vector and so are the elements that were stored in it. If `n` is a constant known at compile time, you might also consider using `std::array` instead.

Comment: If I don’t need to resize my array, memory is tight, and elements of the array are referenced extremely frequently, is it still appropriate to use std::vector?

Comment: @Darksair: Yes, memory overhead of using `std::vector` will be only few bytes (maybe about 16) for storing its size and pointers to beginning and the end. Elements are stored in continuous memory, so iterating over elements is same as with raw array.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Very helpful. I'll try to rewrite with std::vector.

Comment: Also this requires that A(0) is copied n times?

Comment: @Darksair: Yes, those elements will be created as copies of `A(0)`

Answer (score 0):

The & operator has a role to change an function parameter or a return variable to a reference.
Without & the value of the variable will be copied into a temporal variable, therefore the original variable will not be sensible to any value changes.
By referenced handling the parameter will be the original variable only the name differs, but signs the same memory block.
In this example the `b.at(i)` statement will be copied into a temporary constant variable, which is unusable in the left side of = statement.
But by referenced return of this statement it points to the original `As[i]` memory block, only the 'name' differs, and so can be changed its value too.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I guess it just I never used a *& before… :)

Comment: small thing. but don't forget, the * belongs to the type name (makes pointer), when the & is its whole reference modifier